# Equality reflection without $\eta$

Tags: type-theory

Are type theories with equality reflection (i.e. having a term of an identity type between two objects allows us to freely swap them) but not the $\eta$-rule for $\Pi$-types interesting?

Does function extensionality have to hold in such a type theory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extensional type theory and function extensionality](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46331/extensional-type-theory-and-function-extensionality)

Comment: @AndrejBauer no because we don't assume $\eta$

Comment: Is it interesting is subjective, but I expect that you do not obtain function extensionality in such a type theory. Intuitively, equality reflection collapses the difference between internal and external equality, but without funext externally, this collapse won't imply funext internally.

Comment: I think it's not too much work to cook up a category which has finite limits and a weaker form of dependent product without unicity to actually prove this.